# Doble llamada en ruta app.get (node & express.js)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, callback

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de rutas con express y node y en la terminal me he dado cuenta que me hace un doble call cuando accedo a la ruta desde el chrome.

Código del .get

```
app.get('/random-beers', (req, res) => {
punkAPI.getRandom().then(randomBeer => {
    console.log('random beer', randomBeer.length);
    res.render('random-beers', randomBeer[0]);
  });
});
```

Devolución de la consola al acceder a la ruta

```
[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
‍ on port XXXX
random beer 1
random beer 1
```

Por qué pasa esto?

Comment: Prueba a poner un punto de parada o console.log(), entre la petición y la llamada a punkAPI.getRandom(), para ver si lo que se está llamando dos veces es el callback o la petición. Recuerda que con express también puedes hacer 2 declaraciones de la misma ruta, revisa que no tengas otra llamada para la misma ruta.

Comment: creo que haces la petición 2 veces y por eso te salen 2 `console.log`